# Insert from php 5.6 into mariadb 10.1 not inserting some rows

Tags: php, mariadb

I have a strange problem with a test script for which I'm having a hard time to solve since yesterday.

My php script works like this:
I have a xml file with around 1000 items, each with around 10 fields.
I run a php script that reads the xml, escapes each field with mysqli and inserts into mariadb 10.1 in batches (currently doing it one by one).

The funny thing is, it inserts around 960 rows without problems, but around 20 to 30 are not inserted, and this is where the problem lies.

When I say it's not inserting, I mean that even a few minutes after running the script, I go to phpmyadmin (or command line) and cannot find those rows there at all (query by id, or unique field, name, etc).

If I print the query and insert it via phpmyadmin, it goes in without problem.

BUT, when I insert them via php it shows that it was inserted and even returns the id (no errors):

```
printf ("New Record has id %d.\n", $mysqli->insert_id);
```

So I grab the id, go to phpmyadmin and nothing there with that id (but autoincrement has increased).

Even funnier is, that if I query by id on php, it shows the result... but it's not in the list if I select all rows (also on php).

So the rows are there on php when I select by id, but that id doesn not exist via command line or phpmyadmin.

Some of those records eventually show up in a few minutes, but most still don't show on phpmyadmin even after several hours.

Its like some of my inserts are being queued, some inserted and being discarded, and others going in without any problem.

Is this a new feature or bug from php or mariadb 10.1 that I haven't read about?

I'm going to debug this further, but here's some code:

```
# use dom and xpath
$xml = simplexml_load_file($tmp);
if(is_object($xml)) { echo "XML is an object...<br />"; }
foreach ($xml->job as $r) { 
if(isset($r->uid)) {

# filter data
$uid = $mysqli->real_escape_string(trim($r->uid));
$date = $mysqli->real_escape_string(date('Y-m-d H:i:s'));
$title = $mysqli->real_escape_string(trim($r->title));
$descr = $mysqli->real_escape_string(trim($r->descr));
$company = $mysqli->real_escape_string(trim($r->company));
$loc = $mysqli->real_escape_string(trim($r->loc));
$contact = $mysqli->real_escape_string(trim($r->contact));

$jobs[$uid] = "('$uid', '$date', '$title', '$descr', '$company', '$loc', '$contact')";
echo "<br />Found item: $uid / <b>$title</b>";

} 
}


# insert in chunks of 10 (also tried REPLACE INTO with same results)
if(count($jobs) > '0') { 
echo '<br />Inserting data...<br />';
$chunks = array_chunk($jobs, 10); foreach ($chunks as $chunk) { $insert = implode(", ", $chunk);
$result = $mysqli->query("INSERT INTO core_jobs_tmp (uid, date, title, descr, company, loc, contact) VALUES $insert"); 

$nid = $mysqli->insert_id;
printf ("New Record has id %d.\n", $mysqli->insert_id);

# check if it's there (debug: usually it's returns the result correctly)
$sql = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM core_jobs_tmp WHERE id = '$nid'"); 
if (mysqli_num_rows($sql) > '0') { while($r = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)) { echo '<br />'.$r['title'].'<br />'; } }

} 
}
```

Sample xml with 2 items that are not working on insert from php:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<ads>
<job>
<url><![CDATA[someurlhere]]></url>
<uid><![CDATA[42f4505cdb6c637777e7cdfd2ab9f354]]></uid>
<company><![CDATA[Empregos Work]]></company>
<site><![CDATA[indeed.com.br]]></site>
<country><![CDATA[br]]></country>
<date><![CDATA[2016-01-30]]></date>
<loc><![CDATA[Rio de Janeiro, RJ]]></loc>
<title><![CDATA[Assistente Administrativo Júnior]]></title>
<descr><![CDATA[Empresa: 
Apenas usuários logados
Cargo: 
Assistente Administrativo Júnior
Nível do cargo: 
Nível Operacional
Contrato: 
Temporário
Sexo: 
Indiferente
Quantidade: 
Salário: 
R$ 970,00
Cidade: 
RIO DE JANEIRO
Local de Trabalho: 
não disponível
Benefícios: 
Vale transporte
Requer Experiencia em: 
Experiência anterior na área administrava e atendimento ao cliente
Formação Academica: 
Ensino Médio Completo
Competências /
Características Pessoais: OBS: Oportunidade Temporária 3 meses
Atividades: 
Atendimento ao cliente, conferência de documentos e lançamento de dados no sistema próprio da empresa.
Disponibilidade para viagens: 
É necessário ter carro próprio:]]></descr>
<contact><![CDATA[someurlhere]]></contact>
</job>
<job>
<url><![CDATA[someurlhere]]></url>
<uid><![CDATA[02b5af5d2cc279890aae6f12db7003df]]></uid>
<company><![CDATA[Empregos Work]]></company>
<site><![CDATA[indeed.com.br]]></site>
<country><![CDATA[br]]></country>
<date><![CDATA[2016-01-30]]></date>
<loc><![CDATA[Rio de Janeiro, RJ]]></loc>
<title><![CDATA[Assistente Comercial]]></title>
<descr><![CDATA[Empresa: 
Apenas usuários logados
Cargo: 
Assistente Comercial
Nível do cargo: 
Nível Operacional
Contrato: 
Efetivo
Sexo: 
Indiferente
Quantidade: 
Salário: 
R$ 2.300,00
Cidade: 
RIO DE JANEIRO
Local de Trabalho: 
não disponível
Benefícios: 
Vale transporte, vale refeição, plano de saúde e odontológico.
Requer Experiencia em: 
Experiência anterior na função.
Formação Academica: 
Possuir ensino superior completo ou em andamento
Atividades: 
Venda interna e externa de serviços.
Disponibilidade para viagens: 
É necessário ter carro próprio:]]></descr>
<contact><![CDATA[someurlhere]]></contact>
</job>
</ads>
```

Table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `core_jobs_tmp` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `uid` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
  `date` datetime NOT NULL,
  `title` varchar(128) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `descr` mediumtext NOT NULL,
  `company` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
  `loc` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
  `state` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
  `city` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
  `contact` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `paid` int(2) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0'
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;


ALTER TABLE `core_jobs_tmp`
 ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`), ADD UNIQUE KEY `uid` (`uid`), ADD KEY `date` (`date`), ADD KEY `paid` (`paid`), ADD FULLTEXT KEY `title` (`title`,`descr`,`company`,`loc`);

ALTER TABLE `core_jobs_tmp`
MODIFY `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
```

And my mariadb config:

```
[mysql]
port = 3306
socket = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock

[mysqld]
user = mysql
default-storage-engine = InnoDB
socket = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
pid-file = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
bind-address = 127.0.0.1
character-set-server = utf8
collation-server = utf8_general_ci

# MyISAM #
key-buffer-size                 = 8M
myisam-recover-options          = FORCE,BACKUP

# SAFETY #
max-allowed-packet              = 32M
max-connect-errors              = 1000000000
explicit_defaults_for_timestamp = 1

# DATA STORAGE #
basedir = /usr
tmpdir = /tmp
datadir = /var/lib/mysql/

# BINARY LOGGING #
log-bin                        = /var/lib/mysql/mysql-bin
expire-logs-days               = 7
sync-binlog                    = 1

# CACHES AND LIMITS #
tmp-table-size                 = 128M
max-heap-table-size            = 128M
query-cache-type               = 0
query-cache-size               = 0
max-connections                = 1024
thread-cache-size              = 1024
wait_timeout                   = 3600
open-files-limit               = 65535
table-definition-cache         = 4096
table-open-cache               = 4096

# INNODB #
innodb_thread_concurrency      = 0
innodb-flush-method            = O_DIRECT
innodb-log-files-in-group      = 2
innodb-log-file-size           = 384M
innodb-flush-log-at-trx-commit = 0
innodb-file-per-table          = 1
innodb-buffer-pool-size        = 1800M

# LOGGING #
log-error                      = /var/log/mysql/mysql-error.log
long_query_time                = 2
log-queries-not-using-indexes  = 0
slow-query-log                 = 1
slow-query-log-file            = /var/log/mysql/mysql-slow.log

# Fine Tuning #
thread_stack    = 256K
ft_min_word_len = 3

[mysqldump]
quick
quote-names
max_allowed_packet  = 512M
```

Some server info:

```
Server version: 10.1.10-MariaDB-1~jessie-log - mariadb.org binary distribution
Server charset: UTF-8 Unicode (utf8)
Database client version: libmysql - 5.6.24
PHP extension: mysqli 

phpMyAdmin Version information: 4.2.12deb2+deb8u1

php -v PHP 5.6.14-0+deb8u1 (cli) (built: Oct  4 2015 16:13:10)
Copyright (c) 1997-2015 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.6.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2015 Zend Technologies
with Zend OPcache v7.0.6-dev, Copyright (c) 1999-2015, by Zend Technologies
```

Comment: You are talking about INSERTing but using REPLACE? What happens if you use INSERT in an clean data base?

Comment: I though that inserting was failing (but no error), so I changed it to replace (still no dice). I'm inserting this on a clean new database.

Comment: Reason number 1 for failing INSERT is duplicate key. In your case duplicate uid. Are you absolutely sure that uid is unique?

Comment: I'm doing 
$jobs[$uid] = "values"; to avoid duplicates.

Comment: Actually, i found out what's going on. Database was corrupted somehow. I  mysqldump it back to another database on mariadb 10.0 and back to mariadb 10.1 and it's working now. Strange issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, i solved it. 
Database or installation was corrupted somehow. 
I mysqldump the database to another database server on mariadb 10.0 and it was working.
So I purged and reinstalled mariadb 10.1 and mysqldump it back from mariadb 10 to mariadb 10.1 and it's working now. Strange issue, but it worked.

Comment: Suggest deleting the question since it does not provide any useful info for others.

Comment: We do not recommend deleting questions with answers because doing so deprives future readers of this knowledge. Repeated deletion of answered questions can result in your account being blocked from asking. Are you sure you wish to delete? --> therefore, I would rather leave it. Also, although not much information, someone facing this problem, might solve it the same way.

Comment: Verry usefull to me today =) thanks for not delete this answer.